# Console vs scripting python constants

Tags: python, scripting

Using 2.67b for python scripting I get this:
while importing `math`, `numpy` on the scripting console, internal variables seem to be fine
but when running scripts need to manually define numbers likely to be enabled when importing `math`, `numpy` like `PI`, `E`, `C` and several others I think.

Could that be a version problem or do you have to manually define each variables and constants over the scripting editor?

Answer (score 10):

The python console has various convenience imports, `from math import *`  being one of them.

Text from the console:

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.3.2 (default, May 21 2013, 15:40:45)  [GCC 4.8.0 20130502 (prerelease)]

Command History:     Up/Down Arrow
Cursor:              Left/Right Home/End
Remove:              Backspace/Delete
Execute:             Enter
Autocomplete:        Ctrl-Space
Zoom:                Ctrl +/-, Ctrl-Wheel
Builtin Modules:     bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports: from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

>>> pi
3.141592653589793
```

Importing the entirety of a module using `*` when not experimenting in the console is generally seen as bad practice / not pythonic, [and explained in part here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/howto/doanddont.html).

> Remember, you can never know for sure what names a module exports, so
>   either take what you need — `from module import name1, name2`, or keep
>   them in the module and access on a per-need basis

For scripting outside of the console use explicit imports. Create a template with all your frequently used imports, similar to this, and place it in the `../scripts/templates_py/` folder:

```
import bpy
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from math import pi, sin, cos, tan
```

[this article goes into great detail](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) about code structure and includes a short section on imports, definitely food for thought if the topic isn't well understood.

Comment: the alternative would be `import math` and then access `math.pi, math.sin` etc. For maths this would be overkill, but for more complex modules you should consider that. It also becomes important if you use both `math` and `cmath`. And it's noteworthy that you can do things like `from math import sin as sine` in order to give you more freedom with your own variables' names